# My raspberry is not available from local network

Tags: networking, wifi, ping

I have an old raspberry pi 2011.12. It has installed an up to date raspbian (headless).

It is connected to my local wifi network and internet. SSH is enabled. The following commands work fine on the raspberry:

```
ping google.com
ping loclahost
ssh localhost
```

[image]

However when I ping to raspberry from other devices (tried few of them) or ssh - it does not work. I am trying to access using ip address 192.168.1.167. The ip address I determined correctly (it is different for wifi and ether connection).
It is working fine when I connect the raspberry to my router via cable.

P.S. It may be the issue not only with wifi connection but it seems with ethernet I have the same issue. Sometimes this issue disappears but in most case I cannot ping the board from outside.

Comment: Unless the openssh daemon has been configured to bind against a specific IP address it should bidn to all available network addresses.    Whats your network configuration for the wifi on the PI?

Comment: Added my `iwconfig` output

Comment: what is the IP address of the device sending the ping

Comment: Pinging from 192.168.1.169 but also pinged from phone (in the same wifi network)

Comment: Does you home router block local connections.  Check the control panel http://192.168.1.1 or http://192.168.1.254 settings for "WiFi Isolation" or "wireless isolation".

Comment: Yes as Dougie says its possible that the Wifi is isolating the PI's wifi assigned  address..      Have a look at your routers settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your ifconfig report says the WLAN IP address is 192.168.1.167, but you say you are trying to ping the address 192.168.167. That is the problem.

[Update] If you were actually trying to ping 192.168.1.167, then check the IP address of the system initiating the ping; is it also in the 192.168.1 subnet? If not, then check the settings in the device that should be doing the routing between the two subnets.

Comment: Typo... I was pinging 192.168.1.167

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked the IP address. The information is in my screenshot in the question.